# Radio button with text input field

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have an edit page where one of the fields can either be X, Y or a custom string. The image below is the desired result. But instead of the "text field here" it should just be an input field.

[image]

We've attempted to just make a seperate string field for this and attach the two forms but its clunky and I'm 100% sure there's a cleaner way of doing it

```
<RadioButtonGroupInput
  label="Radio Input"
  source="someSource"
  optionText="custom"
  choices={[
    { id: "option-1", name: "Option 1" },
    { id: "option-2", name: "Option 2" },
    { id: "custom", name: "Custom option" }
  ]}
/>
```

From what I understand from the react admin documentation this is how you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-admin provides no way for doing that. The creation of a custom option is supported in `<SelectInput>`, `<AutocompleteInput>`, `<SelectArrayInput>`, and `<AutocompleteArrayInput>`, but not in `<RadioButtonGroupInput>`.

You'll have to write your own Input component. [This PR](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/6215) may be a good inspiration.

Comment: Honestly, not surprised. Thank you for the answer though.